# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing this console error while running my code:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Complete log

```
at renderUserBlocks (eval at globalEval (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:692:47)
    at Object.success (eval at globalEval (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:242:17)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at z (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

My Code

```
function renderUserBlocks(blocksResults){
        var $blocksRows = $('#blocks_rows');
        for (var i = 0; i < blocksResults.length; i += 2){
            var block = parseUserBlock(blocksResults[i + 1], blocksResults[i]);
            var blockJson = JSON.stringify(block);
            var existingRow = document.getElementById('blockRow' + block.time);
            if (existingRow && existingRow.getAttribute('data-json') !== blockJson){
                $(existingRow).replaceWith(getUserBlockRowElement(block, blockJson));
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
            }
            else if (!existingRow){
                var blockElement = getUserBlockRowElement(block, blockJson);
                var inserted = false;
                var rows = $blocksRows.children().get();
                for (var f = 0; f < rows.length; f++) {
                    var pTime = parseInt(rows[f].getAttribute('data-time'));
                    if (pTime < block.time){
                        inserted = true;
                        $(rows[f]).before(blockElement);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!inserted)
                    $blocksRows.append(blockElement);
                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
            }
        }
    }
```

error shows on this line

```
for (var i = 0; i < blocksResults.length; i += 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `blocksResults` is `null` and it does not have a `length` property.
You can check it just before your for loop

```
if (blocksResults) {loop here}
```

Comment: @gosdorxda I'm not sure to understand what do you mean, can you show a working example?

Comment: if not you can always put a braking point in `renderUserBlocks` function, inspect the `blocksResults` parameter, then debug the execution

Comment: example for blocks data: `1548419263:1548427294:10663487991931:208790000:208790000:10588843575987:1::0:180283045",
    "265117"`